# Drush installation issue

Tags: drush, composer

I am trying to install the most uptodate version of Drush as I begin working on Drupal 8.

Apt-get only installs Drush version 5.10.0. So, I'm attempting to install Drush via composer with the following effect:

```
sisko@li184-76:~$ composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
Changed current directory to /home/sisko/.composer
The "fxp/composer-asset-plugin" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("1.0.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("1.1.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
./composer.json has been updated
The "fxp/composer-asset-plugin" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("1.0.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("1.1.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drush/drush[dev-master].
    - drush/drush dev-master requires consolidation/robo dev-master -> satisfiable by consolidation/robo[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - fxp/composer-asset-plugin v1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - fxp/composer-asset-plugin v1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - fxp/composer-asset-plugin v1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for fxp/composer-asset-plugin 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by fxp/composer-asset-plugin[v1.0.0].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
sisko@li184-76:~$ drush status
The program 'drush' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install drush
sisko@li184-76:~$
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Drush via `composer require` rather than `git clone` followed by `composer install` (which is slightly easier), then I would recommend:

1. Use the stable version of Drush, ~8
2. Install with [cgr](https://github.com/consolidation/cgr)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this headache

for me the best option was:

1. login als root
2. `~$ php -r "readfile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush`
3. `~$ php drush core-status`
4. `~$ chmod +x drush`
5. `sudo mv drush /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

I installed drush following this tuto http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/138/install-and-update-drush-on-linux

```
php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
chmod +x drush
sudo mv drush /usr/local/bin
drush init
```

Answer (score 0):

> You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.

As per above warning suggestion, try:

```
composer update --no-plugins
```

and try again as your composer could be out of date. You can also add `--no-plugins` to `composer global require` command to see if that will help.